# How can I map classes/labels to integers and convert them to tensors

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I have images and corresponding labels, but the labels are given as words (strings). I created a dataset class and parse function to parse the data. Now, the problem I have is that when I create a batch, I need to put the labels on the GPU just like the data and model so as to make predictions. The problem is the labels are still a tuple of strings(labels corresponding to the images in the batch). I've tried mappings labels to integers but I probably do not know how to do this, let alone convert them into tensors.

Here is my dataset class

```
def parse_data(Images_folder, train_df):
    img_list = []
    label_list = []
    for filename, label in zip(train_df['img_IDS'], train_df['Label']):
      full_name = filename + ".jpg"
      filei = os.path.join(Images_folder, full_name)
   
      img_list.append(filei)
      label_list.append(label)

    # construct a dictionary, where key and value correspond to ID and target
    uniqueLabel_list = list(set(label_list))
    class_n = len(uniqueLabel_list)
    # label_list = [target_dict[ID_key] for ID_key in ID_list]
    i = 0
    class_int_list = []
    for clas in uniqueLabel_list:
      class_int_list.append(i)
      i += 1 
    
    # target_dict = {x:y for x, y in  zip(uniqueLabel_list, class_int_list)}

    print('{}\t\t{}\n{}\t\t{}'.format('#Images', '#Labels', len(img_list), len(set(label_list))))
    return img_list, label_list, class_n



class TestImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, file_list,file_names, transforms):
        self.file_list = file_list
        self.tranformations = transforms
        self.filenames = file_names
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.file_list)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img = Image.open(self.file_list[index])
        img = self.tranformations(img)
        return img
    def returnNamesList(self):
        return self.filenames
```

This is the image parser function

```
def parse_test_data(Images_folder, test_df):
    img_list = []
    file_names = []
    for filename in test_df['img_IDS']:
      full_name = filename + ".jpg"
      file_names.append(full_name)
      filei = os.path.join(Images_folder, filename)
      img_list.append(filei)
         
    print('#Test Images', len(img_list))
    return img_list, file_names
```

Comment: I am going to skip across most of the technical approach here and just answer your question, you can encode your labels with a label encoders, sklearn provides several ways to encode your labels, I suggest you research which one would be most applicable for your needs. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html